# python object cannot find attribute error

Tags: python, class, static, attributes

I have a file parser.py

```
class Parser:
    ...
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def someMethod():
        Parser.argsParser.someNewMethod()
```

And a file worker.py

```
import connection, parser
...
...

class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            parsed = parser.Parser()
```

And a file driver.py:

```
sys.path.append('./lib')
import worker, parser

parser.Parser.someMethod()
```

Now my directory structure is

```
/some/path/driver.py
/some/path/lib/worker.py
/some/path/lib/parser.py
```

When I run driver.py I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lib/worker.py", line 13, in __init__
    parsed = parser.Parser()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Parser'
'module' object has no attribute 'Parser'
```

However, when I copy driver.py into ./lib and run, I do not find any problems. Can anyone point me to what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a builtin Python module called [`parser`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/parser.html), which is being imported instead of your module.  The best solution is don't name your module that, or, if you do, put it inside a package so you don't import it directly at the top level (i.e., so you do `import mypackage.parser` instead of `import parser`).

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have a __init__.py  file in your lib directory. Then you can import the Parser class in your driver.py file as follows:

```
from lib.parser import Parser
```

The __init__.py file lets the python interpreter know that the directory is to be considered a python module (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: thanks! this clarifies some of the usage of __init__.py, I however have to accept the other answer as it was more accurate to the question :)

Answer (score -1):

Set your PYTHONPATH properly:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/some/path:/some/path/lib
```

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with paths, the problem is not being able to find the class "Parser" and NOT the file "parser.py"